# Character functions vs string functions

Tags: c

I just found a short code here, which would detect blank lines in a file. It used fgets() function in C library.
I wonder if character functions are better suited for files which have tabs, and perhaps continous spaces. 
My qustion is what is the best way to parse a file for blank lines?

Comment: What do you call a character function ?

Comment: There's no function out of the box that can read lines, skipping _lines_ that only contain whitespace characters, you're probably better of using `fgets` and iterating the chars, using `isspace` to skip over whitespace

Comment: would that handle tabs also?

Comment: Read the docs! http://linux.die.net/man/3/isspace

Comment: I should have. You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `scanf(" %[^\n]s",string);` in order to read spaces  but  fgets is best solution for your case.